# Do Torrents have file quantity limitations?

Tags: filesystems, bittorrent, file-sharing, utorrent, peer-to-peer

Is there a limit to the number of individual files that may be included in the root of torrent? If there is a maximum quantity, what is it? If limits are client / tracker dependent, what are the limits for mainstream clients / trackers?

Could I make a torrent with 5 million files?

Comment: Here's a related discussion: https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/5763-utorrent-cant-handle-big-torrent-file/

Comment: I suspect the file size limitation would be imposed by the OS not by the BitTorrent protocol.

Answer (score 2):

One of the torrent file spec descriptions is over [here](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification).

The file format itself doesn't really have limitations like you're asking about. There might be one related to hash collisions but those are pretty unlikely to occur naturally.

Torrent utilities themselves may impose limits. The main one is, while integers in the torrent files have no upper bound, software may impose a 64 bit limit making the upper bound 2^64-1 at most. Given that this number is far larger than the storage capacity available to most people, it's unlikely you'll hit it. (To quote [HG2G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy): "Space is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist, but that's just peanuts to space.")

Next are practical limitations: Your available memory and storage capacity will impose the usual limits.